# Add a Dense after conv layer

Tags: keras, keras-layer

```
import keras.layers as KL
input_image = KL.Input([None, None, 3], name = 'input_image')
x = KL.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same')(input_image)
```

after Conv, I want to add a dense as below:

```
KL.Dense(2)(KL.Flatten()(x))
```

but there will be an error:

> ValueError: The shape of the input to "Flatten" is not fully defined
>   (got (None, None, 64). Make sure to pass a complete "input_shape" or
>   "batch_input_shape" argument to the first layer in your model.

So if I want a model contained conv followed by dense which can accept any size of input, how should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Neural networks don't work with variable sized inputs. Unless you are dealing with recurrent neural networks.

With a network with variable sized input, what would the weights of the network look like?

Typically, you will pick a size for your input layer and resize or pad your input to match that size.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not the same as flattening your input you could use [Global Max Pooling](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/#globalmaxpooling2d):

```
 x = KL.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)
```

This will change your dimension from `(None, None, None 64)` to `(None, 64)` (including batch dimension). Global Max Pooling is a common way to close up convultional Networks and feed the output into a Dense Neural Network.

Answer (score 1):

To build a CNN model you should use a pooling layer and then a flatten one, as you can see in the example below.

**The pooling layer will reduce the number of data to be analysed** in the convolutional network, and then we **use Flatten to have the data as a "normal" input to a Dense layer**. Moreover, **after a convolutional layer, we always add a pooling one.**

The example below is for **1D CNN** but has the same structure as the 2D ones. Again, Flatten() changes the shape of the output to use properly in the last Dense layer.

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(num_filters_to_use, (filters_size_tuple), input_shape=features_array_shape, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```